# How to build a debug android apk so BuildConfig.DEBUG is true?

Tags: android, debugging, build, apk

There are places in the code I use the flag BuildConfig.DEBUG, where can I set this flag and how can I make a debug android apk so BuildConfig.DEBUG is true?

Comment: Do you mean to have a debug app that shows runtime errors like the LogCat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where can I set this flag

It is set for you automatically when you create a `debug` build. You can use the Build Variants view in Android Studio to choose what build is used when you run your app from the IDE.

If you create custom build types, you can use `debuggable true` to mark them as debuggable, and they will have `BuildConfig.DEBUG` set to `true` as well.

Answer (score 2):

When you run your project in Android Studio. The apk that it install in your testing device is the debug apk. You can find the apk in

`YourApplication\app\build\outputs\apk`